# c# finding items from a list with linq to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

Just wondering how would I get something like this to work?

```
void EditListUpdate(int id)
    {
        string[] editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
    }
```

Modules is a list.

Comment: It's not correct, as ToArray is a method call

Comment: Actually, at second glance try `.ToArray();` - note the parantheses.

Comment: @devdigital - Yeah...I noticed that when I looked again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you posted is your actual code, you're missing the parentheses on `ToArray`.  `ToArray()` is a method call.

```
string[] editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
```

That should resolve the error you saw (`Cannot convert method group 'ToArray' to non-delegate type 'string[]'.  Did you intend to invoke the method?`)

**Updated**

You're new error:  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'stageManagement.Module[]' to string[]'`

You need to change the type of `editListMod` from `string[]` to `stageManagement.Module[]`.  Your LINQ statement will select all `stageManagement.Module` objects that have the matching ID.

In other words:

```
Module[] editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just added the parentheses (whoops :/) But I still get an error http://www.kennyist.com/stackover/Untitled.png

Comment: accord ing to the .png file, the list in "moduls" is not initiallized, that's why you have NullException.

Comment: @Wasafa1 - No.  The info box is listing the exceptions `ToArray()` can throw, not the issue at hand.  The issue at hand is detailed after `Error:`

Comment: @Tim you are right.

Kennyist, the problem is the type returned by the method. you can use explicitly by declaring 
      Module[] editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
or use the super nice c#'s type inference by magic word:
      var editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();

Comment: @Kennyist - are you wanting the modules returned, or just a property from the matching modules?  If it's the latter, you'll need to add a .Select() to the query.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the type returned by the method.

You can use explicitly by declaring

```
 Module[] editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
```

or use the super nice c#'s type inference by magic word:

```
 var editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for mention the use of `var`.  I normally prefer to be explicit when I can, but lots of devs like `var`.

Answer (score 1):

`modules` is of type `Module` in your code. Your `editListMod` is of type `string[]`, so the compiler is telling you that it cannot implicitly convert that to type `Module[]`. To fix this, try:

```
Module[] editListMod = modules.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToArray();
```